# Ubuntu Launcher for android devices?

Tags: launcher, phone, ubuntu-for-android

I know that right now, it's only available for the Google Nexus. I was just wondering, will ubuntu become a "home launcher" for android devices sometime in the future? I really like the OS. I have the HTC one right now, it would be nice to be able to install Ubuntu as a launcher.

Answer (score 0):

No. Ubuntu is not a "home screen" replacement for Android. It is an entire OS replacement.